# Websocket connection failed in Supabase local deployment

Tags: supabase

I'm trying to use Supabase's realtime updates locally, and I'm getting the following error

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:54321/realtime/v1/websocket?apikey=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZS1kZW1vIiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJleHAiOjE5ODM4MTI5OTZ9.CRXP1A7WOeoJeXxjNni43kdQwgnWNReilDMblYTn_I0&vsn=1.0.0' failed
```

The same code seems to be working on prod Supabase. What's going wrong here?

I'm using Supabase CLI v1.29.1, and @supabase/supabase-js v2.2.3.

The same code was working before I updated my whole stack, i.e. updated Supabase CLI as well as @supabase/supabase-js, and moved to Postgres v15 locally (i.e. in config.toml), from v14 previously.

Below is a sample of my TS code

```js
supabase
  .channel("public:table_name")
  .on(
    "postgres_changes",
    {
      event: "*",
      schema: "public",
      table: "public:table_name",
    },
   (payload) => console.log(payload)
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Edit: I tried to use https://realtime.supabase.com/inspector to connect to my local realtime instance but even that errored out with the same error. I'm suspecting the might be some issues in the local Supabase server.

Answer (score -2):

This issue has been resolved in Supabase CLI v1.30.0: https://github.com/supabase/cli/releases/tag/v1.30.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).